# daily, monthly and annual mean

Tags: r

I have data with hourly. I need to convert into daily, monthly and then in the annual.

Also, some dates are missing in that, So i want to include that as well.

```
#Date
24/02/2000/05:25:00 NaN NaN NaN
```

26/02/2000/05:10:00 0.227   0.2002496   0.2009378
26/02/2000/06:50:00 NaN NaN NaN
27/02/2000/05:55:00 0.21    0.1687891   0.1630572
28/02/2000/05:00:00 NaN NaN 0.1265696
28/02/2000/06:35:00 0.136   0.1446176   0.1479067
29/02/2000/05:40:00 0.293   0.2279881   0.1900514
01/03/2000/04:45:00 NaN NaN NaN
01/03/2000/06:25:00 0.322   0.3068518   0.2880579
02/03/2000/05:30:00 0.332   0.2793714   0.2391622
02/03/2000/07:05:00 NaN NaN NaN
03/03/2000/06:10:00 0.335   0.2151302   0.2218139
04/03/2000/05:15:00 0.1 0.1138773   0.1168912
04/03/2000/06:55:00 NaN NaN NaN
05/03/2000/06:00:00 0.117   0.1333082   0.147145
06/03/2000/05:05:00 NaN 0.2426362   0.2401871
06/03/2000/06:40:00 NaN 0.32587 0.2845067
07/03/2000/05:45:00 0.323   0.3143821   0.3096662
08/03/2000/04:50:00 NaN NaN NaN
08/03/2000/06:30:00 0.236   0.23232 0.2300107
10/03/2000/06:20:00 0.113   0.1429935   0.1453774
11/03/2000/05:25:00 0.276   0.3238274   0.3150585
11/03/2000/07:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
12/03/2000/06:05:00 0.215   0.2537585   0.2512374
13/03/2000/05:10:00 0.163   0.2273455   0.2679352
13/03/2000/06:50:00 NaN NaN NaN
14/03/2000/05:55:00 0.09    0.1311507   0.1761056
15/03/2000/05:00:00 NaN NaN 0.1447348
15/03/2000/06:35:00 0.125   0.1232291   0.1387782
16/03/2000/05:40:00 0.019   0.06970426  0.11602
17/03/2000/04:45:00 NaN NaN NaN
17/03/2000/06:25:00 0.194   0.1964414   0.1874403
18/03/2000/05:30:00 0.263   0.2749394   0.242199
18/03/2000/07:05:00 NaN NaN NaN
19/03/2000/06:10:00 0.217   0.217737    0.2183706
20/03/2000/05:15:00 0.253   0.2307511   0.2089891
20/03/2000/06:55:00 NaN NaN NaN
21/03/2000/06:00:00 0.282   0.2413632   0.2511235
22/03/2000/05:05:00 NaN 0.382685    0.3944636
22/03/2000/06:45:00 NaN 0.2734097   0.241442
23/03/2000/05:50:00 0.347   0.3289219   0.3003848
24/03/2000/04:50:00 NaN NaN NaN
24/03/2000/06:30:00 0.18    0.1892378   0.2021516
25/03/2000/05:35:00 0.216   0.1871835   0.206762
26/03/2000/06:20:00 0.189   0.1836237   0.2116453
27/03/2000/05:25:00 0.195   0.1817446   0.1804464
27/03/2000/07:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
28/03/2000/06:05:00 0.208   0.168515    0.1819115
29/03/2000/05:10:00 0.162   0.1598227   0.1689523
29/03/2000/06:50:00 NaN NaN NaN
30/03/2000/05:55:00 0.145   0.1472181   0.1723774
31/03/2000/05:00:00 NaN NaN 0.157723
31/03/2000/06:35:00 0.226   0.2108984   0.2339231

Comment: Please post wanted result, what do you mean by "daily", "monthly"?

Comment: I mean, I want to get single value of each day. Some dates e.g. 20/03/2000 have 2 values at 2 different hour. Now I want to do the average of it. So that I can get one single value of each day.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: For monthly and annual calculation I tried                                            file$dates <- with(file,as.POSIXct(date,format="%d/%m/%Y"))
df <- transform(file,month=as.numeric(format(dates,"%m")),year=as.numeric(format(dates,"%Y")))

ddply(df,.(month),summarize,meaniiserb=mean(IISERB),meaniiser100=mean(IISER_100KM),meaniiser200=mean(IISER_200KM), na.rm=T)

Comment: Average of what? Do you need the average of the hours in the day?? Or??

Comment: Can you post the results you expect from the data above?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about spliting your date variable in year, month, and day and then you want to calculate some grouping statistics of another varibale which you did not include in your example. If that is the case you could do the following:

```
# load package 
library(dplyr)

#Date
 Date <- data.frame( Date =strptime(c("24/02/2000/05:25:00", 
"26/02/2000/05:10:00",
"26/02/2000/06:50:00",
"27/02/2000/05:56:00",
"28/02/2000/05:00:00",
"28/02/2000/06:35:00",
"29/02/2000/05:40:00",
"01/03/2000/04:45:00",
"01/03/2000/06:25:00",
"02/03/2000/05:30:00",
"02/03/2000/07:05:00",
"03/03/2000/06:10:00",
"04/03/2000/05:15:00",
"04/03/2000/06:55:00",
"05/03/2000/06:00:00",
"06/03/2000/05:05:00",
"06/03/2000/06:40:00",
"07/03/2000/05:45:00",
"08/03/2000/04:50:00",
"08/03/2000/06:30:00",
"10/03/2000/06:20:00",
"11/03/2000/05:25:00",
"11/03/2000/07:00:00",
"12/03/2000/06:05:00",
"13/03/2000/05:10:00",
"13/03/2000/06:50:00",
"14/03/2000/05:55:00",
"15/03/2000/05:00:00",
"15/03/2000/06:35:00",
"16/03/2000/05:40:00",
"17/03/2000/04:45:00",
"17/03/2000/06:25:00",
"18/03/2000/05:30:00",
"18/03/2000/07:05:00",
"19/03/2000/06:10:00",
"20/03/2000/05:15:00",
"20/03/2000/06:55:00",
"21/03/2000/06:00:00",
"22/03/2000/05:05:00",
"22/03/2000/06:45:00",
"23/03/2000/05:50:00",
"24/03/2000/04:50:00",
"24/03/2000/06:30:00",
"25/03/2000/05:35:00",
"26/03/2000/06:20:00",
"27/03/2000/05:25:00",
"27/03/2000/07:00:00",
"28/03/2000/06:05:00",
"29/03/2000/05:10:00",
"29/03/2000/06:50:00",
"30/03/2000/05:55:00",
"31/03/2000/05:00:00",
"31/03/2000/06:35:00"), format = "%d/%m/%Y/%H:%M:%S"))


# Split your Date variable in days, months, and years

Date[,"Year"] <- format(Date$Date, format = "%Y")
Date[,"Month"] <- format(Date$Date, format = "%m")
Date[,"Day"] <- format(Date$Date, format = "%d")

# Make up some random variable to calculate summary statistics on

Date[,"Random"] <- sample(seq(1,7,1),size=dim(Date)[1], replace = TRUE)

# Now you can calculate grouped statistics by day, month, or year

MonthMean <- Date %>%
                group_by(Month) %>%
                select(Month, Random) %>%
                summarise(Mean = mean(Random))

# Output 
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Month     Mean
  <chr>    <dbl>
1    02 3.142857
2    03 4.217391
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this code, I also have variable, named as (IISERB) in 2 column. So how to get data with date. I assign dates as  `as.character(file$Date) -> file$date` `time <- as.Date( file$date, "%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: You are welcoome! Please edit your first post. It seems as if you have unquoted the source code. Please do not forget to mark the question as answered. For the next time please provide some reproducible example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I have splited the data in Day,Month and Year then calculated Daymean, Monthlymean and Annualmean

using code:

```
# open the file
file1 <-read.table(file.choose(), header=T)
# View the content of the file
View(file1)

# assign the date
as.character(file1$Date) -> file1$date
time <- as.Date( file1$date, "%d/%m/%Y")

# seperate the day, month, year
file1[,"Year"] <- format(time,  format = "%Y")
file1[,"Month"] <- format(time, format = "%m")
file1[,"Day"] <- format(time, format = "%d")

# to see the updates file
View(file1)

# avearaging the dayily mean then same as month wise 
aggregate(file1[, 2:4], list(file$Day), mean, na.rm=T)
```